# Three.js JSON format material specification

Tags: json, three.js

I am quite new using Three.js and writing an exporter from my own model format to JSON model format resp. scene format to be loaded with Three.js. I don't understand the differences in material JSON specification. Using the Three.js JSONLoader a material spec must define colors like this: ... "colorAmbient":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "colorDiffuse":[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], ... . I tried "colorDiffuse" : 65280, but that doesnt work. Also the "colorSpecular" parameter is not considered by using the JSONLoader. When I inspect the loaded result in Firebug I only see ambient and diffuse color loaded properly.
In contrast the JSON scene format for Three.js defines materials using the parameter list like this:

```
"phong_skin": {
"type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
"parameters": { "color": 0, "ambient": 0, "specular": 16777215, "shininess": 50, ... }},
```

Why are scene and object JSON format so different in material specifications? What about the specular color and specularCoef? Did I miss something?

My simple JSON file (representing a plane):

```
{
    "faces": [40,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,40,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5],

    "materials":[{
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "DbgName":"_global_FLOOR_MAT",
        "colorAmbient":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "colorDiffuse":[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        "colorSpecular":[1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        "opacity":1,
        "specularCoef":128,
        "transparent":false,
        "wireframe":false,
        "blending" : "NormalBlending"
        }],

    "metadata":{
        "formatVersion":3.1,
        "generatedBy":"My Exporter"},

    "normals":[0,-0,1,0,-0,1,0,-0,1,0,-0,1,0,-0,1,0,0,1],
    "scale":1,
    "uvs":[[0,-193.333,0,-0,58,-0,0,-193.333,58,-0,58,-193.333]],
    "vertices":[0,1160,0,0,0,0,1160,0,0,0,1160,0,1160,0,0,1160,1160,0]
    }
```